# VBA Delete values when difference between dates triggered

Tags: excel, vba

The problem is that it deletes values from both rows where the difference occurs.
It should delete values just from the top row where the difference occurs.

So I tried replacing `ws.Cells(RowNo, 3) = " "` with `ws.Cells(FirstDate, 1) = " "` but it doesen't do anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Below is the code:

```
Sub CalculateDate()
Dim Result, RowNo As Long
Dim FirstDate, SecondDate As Date
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

RowNo = 2

    Do Until ws.Cells(RowNo + 1, 2) = ""

    FirstDate = ws.Cells(RowNo, 2)
    SecondDate = ws.Cells(RowNo + 1, 2)

        If DateDiff("d", FirstDate, SecondDate) < 2 Then
        ws.Cells(RowNo, 3) = " "
        End If

    RowNo = RowNo + 1

    Loop

End Sub
```

[image]

KEY:

> Red = where difference between 2 dates <2days
>
> Yellow = where the cell value should be blank
>
> Blue = value should be blank Blue = where cells should not be deleted

Comment: In your logic you are comparing dates in column B and if difference between first date and second date is <2 then you are replacing respective Column C value. Now if your dates are in sequence with different of only 1 day then it will remove all value from Column C except the last one.

Comment: shouldn't it be `ws.Cells(RowNo, 3).ClearContents`?

Comment: @Deepak Yes exactly. I am comparing consecutive dates (row i, row i+1) on column B and if the difference <2days then clear cell on column C that correlates with row i from column B (the top row where the difference is found)

Comment: @HTH, thanks for your reply! This would still do the same thing, it doesen't have to delete values from both rows on column C but only from the top row where the difference is found.

Comment: if it does delete the row below, it means that this latter is meeting the requirement of deletion in subsequent loop. you may want to show your data example

Comment: @Nytro so if you have 3 continue row then it will delete first two row's data in column C. I have tested the code and it is giving expected result. Can you provide some example where you do not want to delete value of Column C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you have to change

```
    If DateDiff("d", FirstDate, SecondDate) < 2 Then
        ws.Cells(RowNo, 3) = " "
    End If
```

with

```
    If DateDiff("d", FirstDate, SecondDate) < 2 Then
        ws.Cells(RowNo, 3).ClearContents
        RowNo = RowNo + 1
    End If
```